# Whats the use of having a lot of gold, when no one buys it?

Tags: currency, inflation

Whats the use of having a lot of gold, when no one buys it?

Is it just to have a stable currency in the case when the value of money drops (inflation)?

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean by “when no one buys it”. Can you explain further what you are asking about?

Comment: You shurely mean something more speical but I answer it as I understand it: When I want to buy something I need money - I cannot buy anything with gold (unless someone accepts it). So I have to sell the gold. But when no one buys it, I cannot get money to buy something.

Comment: I have removed the last question in your post, which is not considered on-topic on this site.

Comment: Why got my question downvoted? I know I can find an answer of this question by googling (nearly every question is solvable by googling), but I so often people write around it. Here I thankfully got an answer which perfectly fits my question.

Comment: If you have it, presumably you bought it. So why do you assume no one would buy it from you? As long as you offer it at or slightly below market rates when you're ready to sell, you should easily find a buyer (who is, not surprisingly, going through the same thought process you did however many days/weeks/months ago when you were the buyer in this same scenario).

Comment: @CactusCake In case of inflation many people will have "less" money. Which in case could result in the situation that no one will buy my gold. This gets worse due to the fact that other people want to sell there gold too.

Comment: I don't understand the question; lots of people buy gold. In fact, on *every single day* when gold was *sold*, there was a buyer willing to buy gold; if there had not been, then there would have been no sale. On which days in history do you believe that there was no gold sold?

Comment: Of course, that risk is inherent with *any commodity*. On the flip side, some people speculate that its value will go up in the future, hopefully outpacing inflation, maybe by a large margin if they're lucky, so they buy it despite the risk (consequently this drives up the price a little). Speculating like this can result in huge gains, huge losses, or breakeven. I'm not advocating for buying gold, just advising possible outcomes that buyers/sellers take into consideration when they act.

Comment: OP is not saying that no one is buying gold now. He’s asking about some point in the future when no one is buying gold.

Comment: @BenMiller indeed, yes. In case of a hard financial crisis when nearly no one has the money to buy gold.

Comment: Ah ok. But that is a far-fetched situation - in record keeping history the price has never dropped to $0, so there has always been a willing buyer even during the worst recessions. Buyers might offer an unfair price, but that's not the same as no one buying. When you're in a recession, the answer to "what the use of having a lot of gold?" is "not much", but if you've let yourself get into that situation, what are you supposed to do about it? Sell for a loss, or wait for things to improve? It all depends on the gold owner's risk tolerance (and cash flow), there isn't a one-fits-all answer here.

Comment: Conversely, if you are the buyer at those worst of times, there's a chance to score a lot of gold on the cheap and make out like a bandit when the economy improves and people are spending more once again. But again, it's a calculated risk (when will the recession end? is this really the cheapest it's going to get or should you wait longer to buy? do you have a reliable income and won't need to sell your gold before the price goes back up?) not everybody has the patience or tolerance for that.

Answer (score 2):

Gold is used to hedge inflation and currency risk.  Really most commodities can serve this function, gold just happens to be the most popular one.  People have an affinity to gold because the dollar used to be specifically backed by, and directly exchangeable for, gold.  Similarly, if you wanted to choose a different commodity to serve as your currency/inflation hedge, gold is easy to store and won't go bad.  It would be hard to hedge your assets with grains because those go bad, or highly utilized commodities like steel or oil because of various market demands.  Of commodities, gold is relatively stable.

I agree with you, that people holding gold to be prepared for the zombie apocalypse have underestimated the other far more immediately pressing problems that would exist if you had to shave off bits of gold to pay for toilet paper.

Comment: So I should keep more many than I invest in gold?

Comment: You should certainly not put all of your money in gold (or any other single asset)

Comment: *People have an affinity to gold because the dollar used to be specifically backed by [it]*... and because it's shiny, don't forget that part. People like shiny things ;-)

Comment: Gold will be useless in a zombie apocalypse  because you can't eat it.  Well, you can but it won't satisfy your hunger :->)

Comment: lol fair points!

Comment: I think that's the whole premise is nonsense that in order to survive a global collapse that you need to buy gold, build a bomb shelter and store food, or own arable land for growing food/animals, etc.  In this day and age, only the exceptional few would be able to live off the land.  The rest of us will be zombie appetizers :->)